# Weird Faces In Models

Tags: modeling

I don't know what I'm missing out here but I cannot seem to make this work. I'm trying to connect 4 Vertexes to make a face but it's not happening.

Please see my video of how I created the model here:
https://youtu.be/nVhMPQ-haig

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: You are doing the right basic thing, you're just having a little difficulty selecting the vertices you want.  It is very easy, especially in wireframe view, to accidentally select a vertex other than the one you want, for example a vertex that is almost directly in front of / behind your intended target.  Try switching temporarily to a different view, such as "Solid," in which it is slightly easier to see the vertices you want / harder to select vertices that are close but behind.

Comment: Yep, just to add on, Z toggles between wireframe and solid.

Comment: And also, you could select both loops, and bridge edge loops

Comment: I'm still getting this weird result  :(

Comment: @Zamboolah hi buddy, try to describe the problem and put a screenshot, before the troll that I mentioned at the beginning is dedicated to harass you, include the steps you are doing, for example if you are doing a vertex bridge or fill vertex or faces, if you go back to the object mode you see something formed, you could also upload your blend to check it and see if there is any problem other than what refers to the edition, such as a damaged file or something similar

Comment: @Nazgûl I will do that now and post the screens later. However, have you seen the video?

Comment: yes i see, pleas send me your blend and i check more easy, I can put the screenshots in the answer

Comment: @Nazgûl download the Blend File here pls?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18lh6AgXxfOMRYKHPjgz0v7qKunnLDdQ8

Also, I did the whole process again to see if I made errors during making of the handle but get the same result

Comment: Here is a video of another attempt from the very beginning but still get the same result.

https://youtu.be/apinNPH0Wpo

I'm scratching my head LOL

Comment: Shown in the video is a result of extrusion of the faces you are trying to bridge which was cancelled and left in place. So there are double vertices all around the end faces. In cases like this select all (or this area with Circle Select in Wireframe mode) and W > Remove Doubles. Then select both faces > Bridge Edge Loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>E</kbd> Edge Bridge

<kbd>F</kbd> Fill / Vertex or Edges

<kbd>Example Vertex, Edges Fill / Vertex, Edges Bridge</kbd>

you can select Edge Rings or Edge Loops

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>ALT</kbd>**+**<kbd>R.M.B.</kbd> Select Loop

slide vertices or edges over faces

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>V</kbd>

**Solution of your problem**

1. turn off the subdivide modifier, then erase those faces that are wrong (so 
   you can understand the process), select the loops and create the bridge 
   edges.
2. next step, slide the vertices along the faces
   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>V</kbd>
   Gently slide the vertices over the face away from the midpoint and 
   repeat the operation with the other loop
3. activate the subdivision modifier and you're done

[image]
[image]

Comment: that is very interesting, and just what I thought should I would be doing. I'll try to replicate what you did and see where I did wrong in my workflow.

Can you do me a favor and check my latest video on my 3rd attemp at modeling the cup? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't (perhaps surprisingly) need to delete the faces before using the 'Bridge Edge Loops' tool.

- Select both faces in face mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> Edge Menu > 'Bridge Edge Loops'

Done.

The tool behaves nicely and removes the internal faces

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you are trying to fill faces that are non-non manifold.

I've marked two faces that you should delete from you're mesh and then try filling in the faces you desire.

[image]

Comment: nopi is a different thing buddy :P

Comment: @Nazgûl thanks for that, i turned off the SUBDIVISION SURFACE MODIFIER and was able to fix it from there :)